# iOS - Moon Calculation for Moonrise and Moonset

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdate

I'm trying to translate a library written in Javascript in order to implement it in Objective C for my iOS application.

The link to the JavaScript library : https://github.com/mourner/suncalc

I got different values for Moonrise and Moonset.

The Javascript library returns :

```
moonrise = Mon Nov 28 2016 06:43:49 GMT+0100 (CET)
moonset  = Mon Nov 28 2016 17:10:33 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

My Objective C implementation returns :

```
moonrise : 2016-11-28 02:00:00 +0000
moonset  : 2016-11-28 01:00:00 +0000
```

I'm facing an issue with this functions :

```
// date/time constants and conversions

var dayMs = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    J1970 = 2440588,
    J2000 = 2451545;

function toJulian(date) { return date.valueOf() / dayMs - 0.5 + J1970; }

function toDays(date)   { return toJulian(date) - J2000; }

function hoursLater(date, h) {
    return new Date(date.valueOf() + h * dayMs / 24);
}
```

My Objective C implementation :

```
// date/time constants and conversions

#define dayMS 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
#define J1970 2440588
#define J2000 2451545

-(double)toJulian:(NSDate *) date
{
    return ([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / dayMS - 0.5 + J1970;
}

-(double)toDays:(NSDate *) date
{
    double tj = [self toJulian:date];

    return tj - J2000;
}



  -(NSDate *)hoursLater:(NSDate *) date :(int) h
{
    double d = ([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) + h * dayMS / 24;

    NSTimeInterval seconds = d / 1000;
    NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];

    return newDate;
}
```

I can't see any mistakes, but my values are false.

*Test Example :*

**Javascript Test**

```
var date = new Date();
var d  = toDays(date);
console.log("d = " + d);
```

d = 6175.947204432916

**Objective C Test**

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
double d = [self toDays:today];
NSLog(@"d = %f", d);
```

d = 127900386826537.265625

If you find something, please let me know.

Comment: Quick question: Is `toJulian:` returning the same response, which I guess not. Then try to check each part of your calculation: Is `date.valueOf()` getting the same as `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)`, etc.

Comment: No, this is where I'm currently investigating.
I really don't understand, is it a Calendar Julian/Gregorian issue ?

Comment: I don't use JavaScript, but what is supposed to return `date.valueOf()`? From what I guess, it's milliseconds from... ? 1970? Do you have two sample values for it (one in for `date.valueOf()`, and the other from `[date timeIntervalSince1970]`?

Comment: date.valueOf() is returning time in milliseconds from 1970 yes.
value of Javascript= 1480337462728 (for today date)
timeInterval1970 = 1480337462320.203125 (for today date)

To julian Javascript =  2457721.0354482406
To julian Objective C = 127901159185053.062500

Comment: How can it be different values ? It's just constants values!

Comment: Got it: To put it simply, `#define dayMS 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`  will replace **exactly** `dayMS` with `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24`. Now, `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / dayMS - 0.5 + J1970` is in fact `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 - 0.5 + 2440588 ` which is different from `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) - 0.5 + 2440588 `. A possible fix is then: `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / (dayMS) - 0.5 + J1970;`, or putting the parenthesis in the `#define`.

Comment: Life saver. Thank you... I feel bad now...
Put your comment in an answer so that I can give you credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is on the `#define` definition.

```
#define dayMS 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
#define J1970 2440588
#define J2000 2451545

-(double)toJulian:(NSDate *) date
{
    return ([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / dayMS - 0.5 + J1970;
}
```

This is translated with:

```
-(double)toJulian:(NSDate *) date
{
    return ([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 - 0.5 + 2440588;
}
```

It simply replace **exactly** the values.
But `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` is different of `([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)`.

A quick solution:

```
return ([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) / (dayMS) - 0.5 + J1970;`
```

Or you can put the parenthesis in the `#define`:

```
#define dayMS (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Another solution (I don't really like #define) and you don't need the parenthesis anymore:

```
const double dayMS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

Comment: So I guess this is the same for the hoursLater function?

Comment: For `double d = ([date timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000) + h * dayMS / 24;` there is no issue if you don't use parenthesis, because there is not issue with priority (*/ vs +-). But I'd strongly suggest to use the `const double` that would avoid the issue (as it's calculated).